# Filter JSON list of dictionaries in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter below JSON and create a separate column for "Number of People" and "Duration" keys. I tried explode function but it is not working.

```
[
  {"name":"Number of People","type":"numeric","value":"1.0"},
  {"name":"Duration","type":"numeric","value":"3.0"},
  {"name":"Other Details","type":"numeric","value":"1.0"}
]
```

Comment: Pls show wexample output with more data.